# Uninstall another MSI on install

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2010

I have a Basic MSI project. I need to remove another MSI product on installation that is now integrated into our main application. I tried to use the upgrade scenarios and treat it as a major upgrade. However, this didn't work because of the upgrade codes not matching I believe.

Next, I also made a custom action that ran msiexec.exe after the CostFinalize (I think this was stated in the Installshield help.) This worked perfectly until I installed on a system that didn't have the installer I was looking to remove. My installer would fail if the other obsolete product was not installed. I tried to put a condition on the custom action set by the system search, but it seems the system search is limited in functionality. I can't just check a reg key and set a boolean property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to consider

1) The UpgradeTable ( FindRelatedProducts / RemoveExisting Products ) can be used to remove ProductCodes associated with another product's UpgradeCode.

2) If memory serves, MSI won't remove a Per-User product during a Per-Machine install ( or the other way around ).  The context has to be the same.

3) The UI Sequence doesn't run during silent installs.

4) You can't run msiexec from the execute sequence because there is a system wide mutex of only one execute sequence per machine.

5) If you schedule in UI ( I already told you that you shouldn't since it doesn't run during silent installs )  there is another mutex that says only 1 UI per process.

If you are going from  per-user to per-user or per-machine to per-machine, I would think it's reasonaable you should be able to do what you want using Upgrade elements / table rows without writing custom actions.   Otherwise you'll need a setup.exe style bootstrapper to handle the uninstall prior to entering the msiexec world.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was able to accomplish what I needed using the Upgrade elements as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in InstallShield 2013 using custom InstallScript.  The script is executed via a custom action in the UI sequence, but I placed it after the "SetupProgress" dialog, i.e. before "Execute Action" instead of after the CostFinalize (as the documentation does say).  I added the condition "NOT Installed" to the action.  If you place this in the suggested order, it will kick off the uninstallation as soon as the installer has initialized.  If you move it to where I did, it doesn't kick off until the user has clicked the final install now button.

The reason to put this in the UI sequence is to get around the one msi installer (or uninstaller) at a time problem.  This simply doesn't work in the execution sequence because of that restriction.

The primary weakness in this method is that as Christopher stated, this won't work in a silent install (that is also found in the IS documentation).  That is the official means for achieving this though. (check out: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpCustomActionMSIExec.htm)  If you can live with that (since silent install is generally as special case scenario), then this works just fine.

As Chris also said, you can't launch the uninstaller ui while the primary ui is running, but that's not a problem with my script because it adds a command line switch to run the uninstaller without the ui (i.e. silently).

My script also avoids having to know the guid of the application you want to uninstall.  Here's the script to bind to the custom action (UninstallPriorVersions is the entry point function):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                            
    //  This template script provides the code necessary to build an entry-point 
    //  function to be called in an InstallScript custom action. 
    //                                                                            
    //                                                                            
    //    File Name:  Setup.rul                                                   
    //                                                                            
    //  Description:  InstallShield script                                        
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Include Ifx.h for built-in InstallScript function prototypes, for Windows 
    // Installer API function prototypes and constants, and to declare code for 
    // the OnBegin and OnEnd events.
    #include "ifx.h"

    // The keyword export identifies MyFunction() as an entry-point function.
    // The argument it accepts must be a handle to the Installer database.

    export prototype UninstallPriorVersions(HWND);

    // To Do:  Declare global variables, define constants, and prototype user-
    //         defined and DLL functions here.

    prototype NUMBER UninstallApplicationByName( STRING );
    prototype NUMBER GetUninstallCmdLine( STRING, BOOL, BYREF STRING );
    prototype STRING GetUninstallKey( STRING );
    prototype NUMBER RegDBGetSubKeyNameContainingValue( NUMBER, STRING, STRING, STRING, BYREF STRING );

    // To Do:  Create a custom action for this entry-point function:
    // 1.  Right-click on "Custom Actions" in the Sequences/Actions view.
    // 2.  Select "Custom Action Wizard" from the context menu.
    // 3.  Proceed through the wizard and give the custom action a unique name.
    // 4.  Select "Run InstallScript code" for the custom action type, and in
    //     the next panel select "MyFunction" (or the new name of the entry-
    //     point function) for the source.
    // 5.  Click Next, accepting the default selections until the wizard
    //     creates the custom action.
    //
    // Once you have made a custom action, you must execute it in your setup by
    // inserting it into a sequence or making it the result of a dialog's
    // control event.


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                           
    // Function:  UninstallPriorVersions
    //                                                                           
    //  Purpose:  Uninstall prior versions of this application
    //                                                                           
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function UninstallPriorVersions(hMSI)
    begin

        UninstallApplicationByName( "The Name Of Some App" );           

    end;


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                           
    // Function: UninstallApplicationByName
    //                                                                           
    // Purpose: Uninstall an application (without knowing the guid)
    //                        
    // Returns: (UninstCmdLine is assigned a value by referrence)
    //      >= ISERR_SUCCESS    The function successfully got the command line.
    //      < ISERR_SUCCESS     The function failed to get the command line.
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function NUMBER UninstallApplicationByName( AppName )
        NUMBER nReturn;
        STRING UninstCmdLine;
    begin           

        nReturn = GetUninstallCmdLine( AppName, TRUE, UninstCmdLine );  
        if( nReturn < ISERR_SUCCESS ) then
            return nReturn;
        endif;

        if( LaunchAppAndWait( "", UninstCmdLine, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT) = 0 ) then 
            return ISERR_SUCCESS;
        else
            return ISERR_SUCCESS-1;
        endif; 

    end;


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                           
    // Function: GetUninstallCmdLine 
    //                                                                           
    // Purpose: Get the command line statement to uninstall an application 
    //                        
    // Returns: (UninstCmdLine is assigned a value by referrence)
    //      >= ISERR_SUCCESS    The function successfully got the command line.
    //      < ISERR_SUCCESS     The function failed to get the command line.
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function NUMBER GetUninstallCmdLine( AppName, Silent, UninstCmdLine )
        NUMBER nReturn;
    begin           

        nReturn = RegDBGetUninstCmdLine ( GetUninstallKey( AppName ), UninstCmdLine );
        if( nReturn < ISERR_SUCCESS ) then
            return nReturn;
        endif;

        if( Silent && StrFind( UninstCmdLine, "MsiExec.exe" ) >= 0 )then
            UninstCmdLine = UninstCmdLine + " /qn"; 
        endif; 

        return nReturn;
    end;


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                           
    // Function: GetUninstallKey
    //                                                                           
    // Purpose:  Find the uninstall key in the registry for an application looked up by name
    //      
    // Returns: The uninstall key (i.e. the guid or a fall back value)
    //                                                                       
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function STRING GetUninstallKey( AppName )
        STRING guid;
        STRING Key64, Key32, ValueName;
    begin

        Key64 = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
        Key32 = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"; 
        ValueName = "DisplayName";

        if( RegDBGetSubKeyNameContainingValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key64, ValueName, AppName, guid ) = 0 ) then
            return guid; // return 64 bit GUID
        endif;

        if( RegDBGetSubKeyNameContainingValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key32, ValueName, AppName, guid ) = 0 ) then
            return guid; // return 32 bit GUID
        endif;

        return AppName; // return old style uninstall key (fall back value)

    end;


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                           
    // Function: RegDBGetSubKeyNameContainingValue
    //                                                                           
    // Purpose:  Find a registry sub key containing a given value.
    //           Return the NAME of the subkey (NOT the entire key path)
    //
    // Returns: (SubKeyName is assigned a value by referrence)
    //      = 0     A sub key name was found with a matching value
    //      != 0    Failed to find a sub key with a matching value
    //                                                                           
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function NUMBER RegDBGetSubKeyNameContainingValue( nRootKey, Key, ValueName, Value, SubKeyName )
        STRING SearchSubKey, SubKey, svValue;
        NUMBER nResult, nType, nvSize;
        LIST   listSubKeys;
    begin

        SubKeyName = "";

        listSubKeys  = ListCreate(STRINGLIST);
        if (listSubKeys = LIST_NULL) then
            MessageBox ("Unable to create necessary list.", SEVERE);
            abort;
        endif;

        RegDBSetDefaultRoot( nRootKey );

        if (RegDBQueryKey( Key, REGDB_KEYS, listSubKeys ) = 0) then    
            nResult = ListGetFirstString (listSubKeys, SubKey); 
            while (nResult != END_OF_LIST) 
                SearchSubKey = Key + "\\" + SubKey;
                nType = REGDB_STRING;
                if (RegDBGetKeyValueEx (SearchSubKey, ValueName, nType, svValue, nvSize) = 0) then
                    if( svValue = Value ) then              
                        SubKeyName = SubKey;     
                        nResult = END_OF_LIST;
                    endif;
                endif;      
                if( nResult != END_OF_LIST ) then                       
                    nResult = ListGetNextString (listSubKeys, SubKey); 
                endif;
            endwhile; 
        endif;

        ListDestroy (listSubKeys );

        if ( SubKeyName = "" ) then
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        endif;

    end;
```